# SQL - group by occurrence and return id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of IDs and value:

```
 ID  Value
 X     1
 X     1
 X     2
 Y     5
 Y     5
 Y     5
 Z     3
 Z     6
```

I want to see which ID contains more than 1 different value. In this case return ID X and Y because X contains[1,2] and Z contains [3,6]:

```
 ID
 X
 Z
```

I have tried this:

```
select ID from
(
    SELECT ID
        ,count(*) over (partition by  [Value]) as c
    FROM mytable
  ) a
  where c>1
```

But this is not returning the desired answer

Answer (score 3):

I prefer aggregating this way:

```sql
SELECT ID
FROM mytable
GROUP BY ID
HAVING MIN(Value) <> MAX(Value);
```

On many databases, the above `HAVING` clause will be *sargable*, meaning that an index on `(ID, Value)` can be used.  The version which checks `COUNT(DISTINCT Value)` may not be able to use such an index.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
SELECT ID
FROM mytable
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Value) > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just group them by ID and check wheter it got more than 1 occurrencies in Value field. Something like this

```
SELECT ID
FROM table
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Value) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable(
 ID     VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
  ,Value  int NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO yourtable
(ID,Value) VALUES
('X',1),
('X',1),
('X',2),
('Y',5),
('Y',5),
('Y',5),
('Z',3),
('Z',6);
```

Other approaches are far better,but I used `Rank` and `Subquery` to distinguish ID with more than `one` occurrence.

```
 SELECT ID
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Rank()
                 OVER(
                   partition BY ID
                   ORDER BY Value) ID2
        FROM   yourtable) a
WHERE  ID2 > 1
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/f9dHn0Vs)